# Why have my window buttons gone missing/been replaced by text?

Tags: graphics, ubuntu-mate, appearance

As seen in this screenshot, all the buttons in terminal and kazam have gone away. This happens with every application. Ubuntu Mate 16.04

[image]

Comment: What do you mean 'gone away'. Do they not do anything on clicking them?

Comment: yes they work on clicking but the buttons are missing

Comment: I'd suggest to re-install Ubuntu, maybe with a different desktop (not Mate).